# How to resolve Download and Picture-in-Picture options not showing when video in transform?

Tags: html, picture-in-picture

Download and Picture-in-Picture options not showing when click vertical ... at right bottom of video. Does anyone have solutions.

```
<div style='transform:translate(0px,0px)'>
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: I made your code into a Stack snippet, and all the options (download, picture in picture) were shown to me as normal. Have I misunderstood your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look like this is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=981127) in chromium, which has been reported nearly a year. It can be reproduced when you have enough window height.

If you don't want to wait until a patch releases, you can implement your own control elements using [Picture in Picture API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/watch-video-using-picture-in-picture).

Btw, since this bug is related to window height, a hacky workaround would be embedding the HTML content into an iframe element (using `srcdoc`), but I would not recommend doing it in production.